# Does Apache2 auto install when installing PHP 7.2?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, php, nginx, php7

Anyone else experiencing this issue? When I installed PHP 7.2, it somehow auto installed Apache2 with it. This is a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 with only nginx installed on it to serve static files.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
apt-get install php7.2
apt-get install php-pear php7.2-curl php7.2-dev php7.2-gd php7.2-mbstring php7.2-zip php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml
```

I only found out after running `apt-get install -y php7.2-fpm` and found a  directive relate to `apache2`. Typing `apache2 -v` lo and behold it's there.

Uh so does `apache2` somehow auto install if you install PHP 7.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install `php7.2` on its own, as you’ve done, then yes: the `php7.2` package depends on either `libapache2-mod-php7.2`, `php7.2-fpm`, or `php7.2-cgi` (non-exclusively). The dependencies are listed in that order, so `apt-get` processes them in that order if they’re not satisfied; so

```
apt-get install php7.2
```

on its own will, by default, install `libapache2-mod-php7.2` to satisfy the dependency, and `libapache2-mod-php7.2` depends on the httpd packages so the end result is that `apache2` is installed.

To avoid this, install the packages you really need, at as high a level as possible:

```
apt-get install php7.2-fpm php-pear php7.2-curl php7.2-dev php7.2-gd php7.2-mbstring php7.2-zip php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml
```

Comment: Thanks. Dumb question, if using your above cmd without installing normally apt-get install php7.2. How does php work? does it function as normal? thanks.

Comment: `php7.2` is a “meta-package” which ensures that one implementation of PHP 7.2 is installed; the implementation of PHP 7.2 in this case is `php7.2-fpm`, so as long as the *latter* is installed, PHP will work.